# AWS Go V2: Role chaining from another account using temporal credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am using the official v2 golang sdk for aws (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2)

I have a problematic that I think it's not being addressed by the SDK in a proper way, following the docs on role chaining from aws (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-role-chaining) when you want to assume a role from another account which is only accesible from temporal credentials (see attached image to understand) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub0du.png)
its not implemented on the sdk properly.

Are there any helper functions to work around this?

I would like to tell the SDK to use the temporary creds from an assume role request.

What I have tried on my code:

```
for i := 0; i <= len(account.Role); i++ {
    if i == 0 {
        result, _ = svc.AssumeRole(&sts.AssumeRoleInput{
            RoleArn:         &account.Role[i],
            RoleSessionName: "test",
        })
    } else {
        fmt.Println("assume role on account 2 with temporal credentials from account 1")
        result, _ = svc.AssumeRole(&sts.AssumeRoleInput{
            RoleArn:         &account.Role[i],
            RoleSessionName: "test",
        })
    }
}
```

Where `account.Role` is a slice such as `[arn:aws:123:role1/role1 arn:aws:321:role2/role2]`

Then the preceeding logic is as follows:

1- Assume starting role from account.Role slice, with the actual credentials from the account 1 (mentioned in picture)

2- Use the temporal sts credentials obtained from step 1 and call the assume role operation on account 2 with this creds.